# What does dispatch_atomic_maximally_synchronizing_barrier(); mean?

Tags: ios, assembly, grand-central-dispatch

Recently I have read the [blog](https://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2014-06-06-secrets-of-dispatch_once.html) from mikeash which tells the detail implementation of `dispatch_once`. I also get the source code of it in [macosforge](http://libdispatch.macosforge.org/)

I understand most of the code except this line:

`dispatch_atomic_maximally_synchronizing_barrier();`

It is a macro and defined :

```
#define dispatch_atomic_maximally_synchronizing_barrier() \
    do { unsigned long _clbr; __asm__ __volatile__( \
    "cpuid" \
    : "=a" (_clbr) : "0" (0) : "rbx", "rcx", "rdx", "cc", "memory" \
    ); } while(0)
```

I know it is used to make sure it "Defeat the speculative read-ahead of peer CPUs", but I don't know that `cpuid` and the words followed. I know little about assemble language.

Could anyone elaborate it for me ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: `CPUID` is one of the non-priviledged serializing instructions on the P6 and later versions of x86. Refer to section 8 ("Serializing instructions") in volume 3 of the [Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

libdispatch source code pretty much explains it.

http://opensource.apple.com/source/libdispatch/libdispatch-442.1.4/src/shims/atomic.h

```
// see comment in dispatch_once.c
#define dispatch_atomic_maximally_synchronizing_barrier() \
```

http://opensource.apple.com/source/libdispatch/libdispatch-442.1.4/src/once.c

```
// The next barrier must be long and strong.
//
// The scenario: SMP systems with weakly ordered memory models
// and aggressive out-of-order instruction execution.
//
// The problem:
//
// The dispatch_once*() wrapper macro causes the callee's
// instruction stream to look like this (pseudo-RISC):
//
//      load r5, pred-addr
//      cmpi r5, -1
//      beq  1f
//      call dispatch_once*()
//      1f:
//      load r6, data-addr
//
// May be re-ordered like so:
//
//      load r6, data-addr
//      load r5, pred-addr
//      cmpi r5, -1
//      beq  1f
//      call dispatch_once*()
//      1f:
//
// Normally, a barrier on the read side is used to workaround
// the weakly ordered memory model. But barriers are expensive
// and we only need to synchronize once! After func(ctxt)
// completes, the predicate will be marked as "done" and the
// branch predictor will correctly skip the call to
// dispatch_once*().
//
// A far faster alternative solution: Defeat the speculative
// read-ahead of peer CPUs.
//
// Modern architectures will throw away speculative results
// once a branch mis-prediction occurs. Therefore, if we can
// ensure that the predicate is not marked as being complete
// until long after the last store by func(ctxt), then we have
// defeated the read-ahead of peer CPUs.
//
// In other words, the last "store" by func(ctxt) must complete
// and then N cycles must elapse before ~0l is stored to *val.
// The value of N is whatever is sufficient to defeat the
// read-ahead mechanism of peer CPUs.
//
// On some CPUs, the most fully synchronizing instruction might
// need to be issued.

dispatch_atomic_maximally_synchronizing_barrier();
```

For x86_64 and i386 architecture, it uses cpuid instruction to flush the instruction pipeline as @Michael mentioned. cpuid is serializing instruction to prevent memory reordering. And __sync_synchronize for the other architecture.

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.2/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html

```
__sync_synchronize (...)
This builtin issues a full memory barrier.
```

> these builtins are considered a full barrier. That is, no memory operand will be moved across the operation, either forward or backward. Further, instructions will be issued as necessary to prevent the processor from speculating loads across the operation and from queuing stores after the operation.

Comment: I had read these links you mentioned, but I still confused these sentences "flush the instruction pipeline" and "serializing instruction". In my opinion, `dispatch_atomic_maximally_synchronizing_barrier();` is like a function used to wait until other CPU to fail on speculation. Am I right? I know `cpuid` is a instruction, but I want to know the meaning of data after `cpuid`. `"cpuid" \
    : "=a" (_clbr) : "0" (0) : "rbx", "rcx", "rdx", "cc", "memory" \.....`

Comment: I have read the document [GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO](http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html) and recognized that `cpuid` didn't do magic things, it just fetch cpu information which takes a decent amount of times to execute and it make the other CPU to fail on speculation.